# How is scikit-learn's FastICA deconvoluting two signals that are each composed of Gaussian noise?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian, noise, dimensionality-reduction

Not sure if best to ask this here or on StackExchange, but since it's a programming question as well as potentially a math question, here goes.

The question is about FastICA.

Given input time series ("observations" below), where each time series is a linear mix of n_components signals, ICA returns the signals and a mixing matrix. From http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~ayuille/courses/Stat161-261-Spring14/HyvO00-icatut.pdf, section 3, I understand that at most one signal may be Gaussian noise. But below I seem to demonstrate that FastICA recovers two signals even when both are noise (here as a function of length of time series from just a single time step to 10000 time steps, for 16 time series):

```
# Snippet below adapted from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_ica_blind_source_separation.html
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
from sklearn.decomposition import FastICA, PCA
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 100, 1000, 10000]: # number of timepoints
    # Generate sample data
    np.random.seed(0)
    n_samples = i
    time = np.linspace(0, 8, n_samples)
    #
    s1 = np.array([np.random.normal() for q in range(i)])
    s2 = np.array([np.random.normal() for q in range(i)])
    #
    S = np.c_[s1, s2]
    S += 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=S.shape)  # Add extra noise, just to muddy the signals
    #
    S /= S.std(axis=0)  # Standardize data
    # Mix data
    A = np.array([[np.random.normal(), np.random.normal()] for j in range(16)]) # Mixing matrix
    X = np.dot(S, A.T)  # Generate observations
    #
    # Compute ICA
    ica = FastICA(n_components=2)
    print i, "\t",
    try:
        S_ = ica.fit_transform(X)  # Reconstruct signals
    except ValueError:
        print "ValueError: ICA does not run"
        continue
    A_ = ica.mixing_  # Get estimated mixing matrix
    #
    # We can `prove` that the ICA model applies by reverting the unmixing.
    print np.allclose(X, np.dot(S_, A_.T) + ica.mean_) # X - AS ~ 0
```

Output:

```
1   ValueError: ICA does not run
2   False
3   True
4   True
5   True
10  True
20  True
100     True
1000    True
10000   True
```

Why does this work? I.e., why is X - AS ~ 0 (the allclose() condition above)? Note it still works if the number of datasets we generate is much larger than the 16 I used here (e.g. 1,000 time series still works).